# how to block all web traffic on a Cisco Aironet 1250

Tags: cisco, access-point

I have a Cisco Aironet 1250 that we're using. I need to be able to configure it (hopefully from the command line, but web could work) to block all http and https traffic.

We are trying to test our software. It needs to be able to handle DNS resolving, but web traffic being blocked (such as when using WiFi at an airport). Our hope is to use our existing router to do this.

Thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that this is primarily an L2 device, meaning that it has no visibility into different types of traffic. You'll need to put blocking rules in place on your firewall, which operates at L3 (or higher).

Comment: Thanks Erik. If that's the case we'll have to try something else.